# Keep getting zeros as Fourier Coefficients

Tags: fourier-series, harmonic-functions

Ive got to solve the Laplace equation in polar form for $r>a$ (where $a$ is a constant) and I've boiled down the problem to 
$$
T=A_0+\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{B_n}{r^n}\cos(n\theta)+\frac{C_n}{r^n}\sin(n\theta)
$$
by using the Boundary Value :
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty} r\frac{\partial T} {\partial r} (r,\theta)=0.
$$ 
I now want to use the Boundary Value $T(a,\theta)=T^*\cos^2(\theta)$ where $T^*$ is a constant, but I keep getting both fourier coefficients equal to zero. NB: I have got $A_0=\frac{T^*}{2}$ Any hints?

Comment: can you explicit what does BV mean? Boundary value maybe? I am trying to guess.

Comment: Yes, should've specified that sorry!

Comment: What's $a$? You said "for $r > a$" but you said that before even mentioning what $r$ and $a$ are.

Comment: $r$ is the polar coordinate and $a$ is a constant, so I am solving the Laplace Equation for the outside of a cirlce

Comment: Okay, you should add that to the question. The domain of definition where you solve Laplace equation is very important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way:
$$ T^* \cos^2{\theta} =  \frac{T^*}{2}(1+\cos{2\theta}). $$
Therefore by orthogonality, the only nonzero coefficients are of $1$ and $\cos{2\theta}$. Fiddling about with the constants gives
$$ T = \frac{T^*}{2}\left(1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}\cos{2\theta}\right). $$

---

Slightly less slick way: $\sin{n\theta}$ is odd, so
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin{n\theta}\cos^2{\theta}\, d\theta = 0, $$
and we can forget about the sine terms.

On the other hand,
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos{m\theta}\cos{n\theta} \, d\theta = \frac{1}{\pi}\delta_{mn} $$
for at least one of $n,m>0$, so the only term you have to worry about is the $\cos{2\theta}$ one, by $ 2\cos^{2}{\theta} = 1+ \cos{2\theta}$ as before. You might want to integrate it directly to check you know what you're doing, but otherwise, it's just a matter of getting the constants right, now that you know where to look.

Comment: By integrating directly you mean I should integrate this correct? $$ \frac{T^*}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos{n\theta}\cos^2{\theta}\, d\theta$$

Comment: Yes, although as I noted above, $n=2$ is the important bit.